# CMake taget_link_libraries has no effect

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying compiling a program using cmake. I write a CMakeLists.txt file but it seems that the statement "target_link_libraries" has no effect. I put "XXX", which is not a library, in the library list on purpose to test if it would give error message like "cannot find library XXX". Unfortunately, I don't get that message and all the error message is about undefined identifiers which should have been defined if the libraries is linked successfully. What's more, when I delete the target_link_libraries statement and compile, I get completely the same error message with what I got previously. This further shows that the target_link_libraries has no effect. Could you please help me find what's wrong in the CMakeLists.txt? I'm using CentOS 6.8 and the compiler is intel icpc 2013 sp1.0.080.
Thanks in advance!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(OFcatalyst)

set(USE_CATALYST ON CACHE BOOL " ")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/bin/intel64/icpc)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -std=c++0x -fp-trap=common -fp-model precise -Dlinux64
#-DWM_DP -wd327,525,654,819,1125,1476,1505,1572 -xHost -O2 -no-prec-div -DNoRepository -fPIC)
set(FOAMDIR /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x)
set(FOAMSRC ${FOAMDIR}/src)
set(FOAMSOLVER ${FOAMDIR}/applications/solvers)
include_directories(
${FOAMSRC}/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude ${FOAMSRC}/OpenFOAM/lnInclude 
${FOAMSRC}/finiteVolume/lnInclude ${FOAMDIR}/interfacialModels/lnInclude 
${FOAMDIR}/phaseModel/lnInclude ${FOAMDIR}/kineticTheoryModels/lnInclude 
${FOAMSOLVER}/multiphase/bubbleFoam 
${FOAMSRC}/turbulenceModels/incompressible/turbulenceModel
${FOAMSRC}/transportModels
${FOAMSRC}/transportModels/incompressible/transportModel
${FOAMSRC}/transportModels/incompressible/singlePhaseTransportModel
${FOAMSRC}/meshTools/meshSearch
${FOAMSRC}/meshTools/lnInclude
${FOAMSRC}/lagrangian/basic/lnInclude)
set(srcfile runCatalyst.C internalWriter.C lagrangianWriter.C writeFuns.C
    writeFaceSet.C writePointSet.C writeSurfFields.C vtkMesh.C vtkTopo.C)
#link_directories(${FOAMDIR}/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib)

if(USE_CATALYST)
find_package(ParaView 5.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS vtkPVPythonCatalyst)
include("${PARAVIEW_USE_FILE}")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${srcfile})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PRIVATE vtkPVPythonCatalyst 
vtkParallelMPI m nsl dl OpenFOAM fileFormats finiteVolume 
triSurface twoPhaseMixture surfMesh meshTools XXX
incompressibleTransportModels incompressibleTurbulenceModel
incompressibleRASModels)
message(status "target-link-libraries is executed")
add_definitions("-DUSE_CATALYST")
if(NOT PARAVIEW_USE_MPI)
message(SEND_ERROR "ParaView must be built with MPI enabled")
endif()
include(vtkModuleMacros)
include(vtkMPI)
vtk_mpi_link(${PROJECT_NAME})
else()
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_C_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${srcfile})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PRIVATE ${MPI_LIBRARIES} 
m nsl dl OpenFOAM fileFormats finiteVolume 
triSurface twoPhaseMixture surfMesh meshTools
incompressibleTransportModels xxx
incompressibleTurbulenceModel
incompressibleRASModels)
endif()
```

Comment: The skill in debugging a problem is to take it out of its original context, by removing as many *specific* things as possible until you arrive at a *generic* description of your problem. As is, your CMakeLists.txt will only work with your specific source tree (and dependencies), and so virtually no-one can reproduce your problem (or test potential answers for correctness). Create a [mcve], please.

Comment: And provide **precise error message**. I guess it is a *compile-time* error about **indeclared** identifier. Because the linking hasn't performed yet, you don't get errors "library not found".

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for your reply! Actually I have written some minor CMakeLists.txt files before and they works properly. This CMakeLists.txt file is based on those previous files and adds some statements for the specific program. This program has to link to two very large C++ libraries so I have to make the CMakeLists.txt like this. Maybe you can just focus on the block of " if(USE_CATALYST) ". Thank you!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply! The errors are indeed about undeclared identifiers, because the program failed to link to the libraries. But what I want to know is why the libraries are not linked to. Here is a part of the error messages:In file included from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/Ostream.H(39),/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/IOstream.H(104): error: identifier "scalar" is undefined
              scalar versionNumber_;

Comment: You can check the cache file (CMakeCache.txt IIRC) in the binary directory to see if the libraries in question have been found in the first place. That would narrow it down a bit.

Comment: OK, thank you! Now I realize that @Tsyvarev is right. It's a **compile-time**  error, so the building process stopped before it reached the step of linking to the libraries. I think I have to revise my program now.